# Java script hangman game issues

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working on a hangman game using an HTML template and javascript for a project for a class.

I am currently stuck with a few issues. 
1. I am using an array to call the pictures for wrong guesses to add parts to the body in the gallows. only picture #4 shows up when 4 incorrect guesses have occurred. 
2. I also have the issue that only for certain words do the buttons decide to actually work and the letter "o" never works

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hangman</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    var NumberOfChances;
    var theWord = "",oldString="";
    var currentGuessed = "";
    var value="";

    var words = new Array();
        words[0]="No strings attached";
        words[1]="Never look back";
        words[2]="Happy birthday";
        words[3]="Against all odds";
        words[4]="Break a leg";
        words[5]="Off the beaten path";
        words[6]="Good old days";
        words[7]="Gold rush";
        words[8]="Happy camper";
        words[9]="Grin from ear to ear";
        words[10]="Live long and prosper";
        words[11]="Quartz watch";
        words[12]="Jumping jacks";
        words[13]="Income tax";

    var image = new Array();
        image[0] = '<img src="image0.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">';
        image[1] = "<img src='image1.jpg' align ='left' width='415' height='496'>";
        image[2] = '<img src="image2.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">';
        image[3] = '<img src="image3.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">';
        image[4] = '<img src="image4.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">';
        image[5] = '<img src="image5.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">';
        image[6] = '<img src="image6.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">';

        NumberOfChances = image.length;



        function swap(image)
{
        document.getElementById("images").src =image+".gif";

}

    var usedLetters = new Array();
    function secretWord()
{
    debugger
        theWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*51)]; 
    for (i=0; i<theWord.length; i++)
{
        currentGuessed = currentGuessed + "*";

}
        document.getElementById("secretWord").value = currentGuessed;
    debugger
}
    function gameProcess()
{
        currentGuessed ="";
        secretWord();
        NumberOfChances=0;
        document.getElementById("lives").value = NumberOfChances;
        startImage = image[0];
} 

    function turn(letterGuessed)
{
    debugger
        value = oldString = "";
    var correctGuess = false;
    for (i=0; i<theWord.length; i++)
{

    if (theWord.charAt(i) == letterGuessed)
{
        value  = value + letterGuessed;
        currentGuessed = currentGuessed.replace(oldString + "*",value);
        oldString = value;
        correctGuess=true;
}
    else
{
    if(currentGuessed.charAt(i) == "*")
{
        value = value + '*';
        oldString = oldString + "*";
}
    else
{
        value = value + currentGuessed.charAt(i);
        oldString = oldString + currentGuessed.charAt(i);
}
}
} 
    if (!correctGuess)
{
        NumberOfChances++;
        swap("image" + NumberOfChances );
    if (NumberOfChances==6)
{
        alert("You Lost!");
        document.getElementById("secretWord").value = theWord;
            theWord = "";
        currentGuessed = "";
}
        document.getElementById("lives").value = NumberOfChances;
    if(correctGuess != 0)
{
        takeChance();
}
}
        win();
}

    function win()
{
    var winCount = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i<theWord.length;i++)
{
        if(currentGuessed.charAt(i) == "*")
{
        winCount++;
}
    document.getElementById("secretWord").value = currentGuessed;
}
    if(winCount == 0 && currentGuessed != "")
{
        alert("yay, you win!");
}

} 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<H1>Lets play Hangman</H1>

<form name="userGuessForm"  id="form1">
<div id="Image"><img src="image0.gif" align ="left" width="415" height="496" id="images"/></div>
<div id="wordDisplay"></div>

This is the Secret Word<br /><input id="secretWord" type="text" value="currentGuessed" />
<br />
<input id="letters" type="button" name="a" value="a" onClick="turn('a');">
<input id="Button1" type="button" name="b" value="b" onClick="turn('b');">
<input id="Button2" type="button" name="c" value="c" onClick="turn('c');">
<input id="Button3" type="button" name="d" value="d" onClick="turn('d');">
<input id="Button4" type="button" name="e" value="e" onClick="turn('e');">
<input id="Button5" type="button" name="f" value="f" onClick="turn('f');">
<input id="Button6" type="button" name="g" value="g" onClick="turn('g');">
<input id="Button7" type="button" name="h" value="h" onClick="turn('h');">
<input id="Button8" type="button" name="i" value="i" onClick="turn('i');">
<input id="Button9" type="button" name="j" value="j" onClick="turn('j');">
<input id="Button10" type="button" name="k" value="k" onClick="turn('k');">
<input id="Button11" type="button" name="l" value="l" onClick="turn('l');">
<input id="Button12" type="button" name="m" value="m" onClick="turn('m');">
<input id="Button13" type="button" name="n" value="n" onClick="turn('n');">
<input id="Button14" type="button" name="o" value="o" onClick="turn('o');">
<input id="Button15" type="button" name="p" value="p" onClick="turn('p');">
<input id="Button16" type="button" name="q" value="q" onClick="turn('q');">
<input id="Button17" type="button" name="r" value="r" onClick="turn('r');">
<input id="Button18" type="button" name="s" value="s" onClick="turn('s');">
<input id="Button19" type="button" name="t" value="t" onClick="turn('t');">
<input id="Button20" type="button" name="u" value="u" onClick="turn('u');">
<input id="Button21" type="button" name="v" value="v" onClick="turn('v');">
<input id="Button22" type="button" name="w" value="w" onClick="turn('w');">
<input id="Button23" type="button" name="x" value="x" onClick="turn('x');">
<input id="Button24" type="button" name="y" value="y" onClick="turn('y');">
<input id="Button25" type="button" name="z" value="z" onClick="turn('Z');"><br />
Number of Tries (6): <input id="lives" type="text" value="0" onfocus="lives.blur();" SIZE=2> 
<input type="button" name="submit" value=" Start Over " onClick="gameProcess()">
<input type="button" name="end" value=" END " onClick="gameEnd()"><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your images aren't working correctly because you're using an array as a string.

```
document.getElementById("images").src =image+".gif";
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("images").src ="image"+NumberOfChances+".gif";
```

otherwise, what you're doing is taking the html of all the images and setting it as the src attribute for your image.

```
<img src="<img src="image0.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">, <img src="image1.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">, <img src="image2.jpg" align ="left" width="415" height="496">..." id="images"> This isn't what you want!
```

And also, I think you've got your jpgs and gifs mixed up. Check your file extensions.

Also, do you have 50 words that you aren't showing here? Your array contains 13, but later you write

```
theWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*51)];
```

And that seems to suggest you have one less than 51, or 50, words.

In your letterGuessed function, I don't think you're quite grasping the concept of for loops. What you seem to be thinking is that a new iteration happens each time you call the function, but that isn't the case. Rather, the for loop goes through the entire word each time you call the function with the one letter you guessed. So unless every single letter in the word is o, if you guess the letter o, you'll get one point for every o in the word, and -1 chance for every character that isn't o, which isn't what you want. Ditch the for loop and just use i++ for each time the function runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function swap(image)
{
        document.getElementById("images").src =image+".gif";

}
```

Try changing gif to jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!correctGuess)
{
    NumberOfChances++;
    swap(image[NumberOfChances]);
```